# Which are the hooks run before/after when a category's deletion?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, hooks, actions

What are the actions that a plugin can hook on to for processing when the user deletes a category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`wp_delete_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_category) is a small wrapper around [`wp_delete_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term) ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1320) ).

It has number of hooks, the one that comes right before delete is:

```
do_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
```

Hooks after delete:

```
do_action( 'deleted_term_taxonomy', $tt_id );
do_action('delete_term', $term, $tt_id, $taxonomy);
do_action("delete_$taxonomy", $term, $tt_id);
```

There are also few earlier hooks that deal with remapping children terms.